# vscode debugger lo longer works on macos after update

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

---

You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software

### to help you develop and test your applications.

Unable to attach to CoreCLR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround posted on [github]
 (https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10279) below.  Confirmed works for me.

---

Here is a work around that worked for Gregg Miskelly:

- Download https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v2/package/runtime.osx.10.10-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR/1.1.2-servicing-25123-01
- Open the resulting file as a zip, and copy out runtimes/osx.10.10-x64/native/libdbgshim.dylib
- Open a terminal
- cd ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.8.0/.debugger
- cp .

As I said above, but just to repeat here, I expect to have a real fix out soon. But hopefully this will unblock folks in the mean time.

Comment: This worked for me as well once I referenced the .vscode folder in my home folder, not the project.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the @bunt answer, in my case it was also necessary delete "bin" folder, close and reopen vscode.